# doxygen latex make fails for input encoding error

Tags: pdf, latex, doxygen, miktex

I have a git repo project in eclipse which I have been documenting using doxygen (v1.8.4).
If I run the latex make ion a fresh clone of the project it runs fine and the PDF is made.
However, if I then run a doxy build, which completes OK, *then* attempt to run the latex make, it fails for

```
! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined 
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `utf8'. 

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation. 
Type  H <return>  for immediate help. 
 ...
```

I have tried switching the encoding of the doxyfile by setting `DOXYFILE_ENCODING` to `ISO-8859-1` with no change in the result... How can I fix this?? Thanks.

EDIT: I have used no non-UTF-8 chars as far as I know in my files, the file referenced before the error is very short and definitely doesn't have non-UTF-8 chars in it. I've even tried clearing my latex output dir and building from scratch with no luck...

EDIT: Irealised that the doxy build only *appears* to run correctly. It doesnt show any errors, but it should, for example run DOT and build about 10 graphs. The console output *says* Running dot, but it doesn't say generating graph (n/x) like it should when it actually makes the graphs...

Comment: Is there any reason for using doxygen 1.8.4? Did you try with 1.8.6? Doxygen does not run dot when no new graphs are created or when a graph has not changed.

Comment: @albert, 1.8.4 was just the last time I updated, was trying to keep tool updates to a minimum mid-project. Do you think this problem could be resolved by 1.8.6 changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: So by a slow process of elimination I found that this was caused by a single apostrophe in a file that had appeared to be already built and made without error!!

Long answer: Firstly I used used the project properties to flip the encoding from the default Cp1252 to UTF-8. Then I started removing files one-by-one until rebuilding and remaking after each removal, until the make ran successfully. I re-added all files, but deleted the content in the most recently removed file and tested the make - to confirm it was this file and *only* this file that caused the issue. the make ran fine. So I pasted the content back into the empty file, and started deleting smaller and smaller sections of the file, again rebuilding and remaking each time until I was left with a good make without the apostrophe and a bad one with it... I simply retyped the apostrophe (as this would then force it to be a UTF-8 char) and success!! Such an annoying bug!

Answer (score 0):

Dude you made it a hard way. Why not use python to do the work for you:

```
f = open(fn,"rb")
data = f.read()
f.close()
for i in range(len(data)):
    ch = data[i]
    if(ch > 0x7F): # non ASCII character
        print("char: %c, idx: %d, file: %s"%(ch,i,fn))
        str2 = str(data[i-30:i+30])#.decode("utf-8")
        print("txt: %s" % (str2))
```

Comment: Any information on what these lines of code do, for those of us that do not know python?